# Editing a resource which is created through a module

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have lots of common modules that I use in my infrastructure. I have been running into a problem lately. I am going to simplify and explain one such instance.

*one code snippet*

```
module "ec2-instance" {
  source  = "../common-modules/ec2-instance/"
  aws_instance="monitoring"
  region="ap-south-1"
  subnets=["subnet-a979cb"]
  ami_id="ami-34b4c05b"
  instance_type="t2.medium"
  instance_count=1
  security_group= "sg-aac36ab3"

}
```

I am using the module (`../common-modules/ec2-instance/`) used in the snippet, in ten different places.

Now, In **one of the ten usages** (ec2 instances), I want to add a tag / userdata / any new attribute, but not to others, i.e I do not want to edit my module source code as it will mess up other 9 places where I have called the module.

Could you please help me how can I achieve this?

Comment: When considering override feature, I am unable to set the right name of the resource.

    ```resource "aws_instance" "module.ec2-instance.aws_instance.template_ec2"{
      tags {
     newtag = "newvalue"
     }
    }```


    $ terraform plan

    ```Error: Error asking for user input: Error parsing address 'aws_instance.module.ec2-instance.aws_instance.template_ec2': invalid resource address "aws_instance.module.ec2-instance.aws_instance.template_ec2"```

Comment: This is a tough one - maybe consider making a branch named `your-branch` of your module for the one-in-ten times you want to apply some kind of modification, then reference it as `source = "../common-modules/ec2-instance/?ref=your-branch"`. See https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/sources.html#selecting-a-revision for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Modules are meant to be used as such; any place where they are used, behaviour and options should be the same. However, what you are trying to do is introduce more variables for the module, without causing changes on any instance of the module except for the one that actually utilises the variable(s).

There is no generic answer other than using the existing values as defaults and then providing variables on your module to allow these defaults to be overridden, only where you want this to happen (e.g. your one module out of 10). The examples you mentioned (tags, userdata etc) are all very different in Terraform behaviour and thus require custom solutions.

Let's go over the examples you gave:

**1) variable tags**: Terraform 0.12.0-alpha1 introduced the [dynamic block feature](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/7034#issuecomment-433511035), which allows you to have exactly zero tags on all resources except for the ones you actually provide tags for, through a variable (e.g. list of maps).

Example:
Your module will have a var called `tags` which can be an empty list by default. Inside your module's resource, you'd implement the following (not tested, just an interpretation of the example in the Git link):

```
dynamic "tags" {
  for_each = var.tags
  tag {
    key = tags.key
    value = tags.value
  }
}
```

**2) variable userdata**

Add a `user_data` variable to your module, with a default value of empty string (Terraform 0.12.0 supposedly has native null support but I have no experience with this in conjunction with user data; AFAIK user data strings still need to be at least 1 char long).

Add some interpolation when assigning the user data:

`user_data = "${var.user_data == "" ? data.template_file.existing_user_data.rendered : var.user_data}"`

The existing user data obviously should be the data that you already have in place on your 9 module instances that shouldn't change. By having this as a default, no changes will be applied except on the module that actually gets passed custom user data, thereby employing an **override strategy**.

**3) Any new attribute**

Same as with the examples above; find a way to have the current value as a default, so that no module sees a change unless it is applied through custom variable input.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a new version of your module and point that one use to the new module version and point the other 9 at the old version, if you're not able to make the existing module work for both uses. [Module versioning](https://www.terraform.io/docs/modules/usage.html#module-versions). You're not able to change the module definition on the fly